# Send email to gmail so it gets added to the calendar

Tags: email, gmail, calendar

What I would like to write an email (doesn't matter the client) and send it to my Gmail account. I would like to craft it in such a way so that Gmail knows that it is an event and can add it to the calendar automatically.

I get emails confirming hotel books and flights that automatically get added. I am wondering if there is some plain text way of writing something and emailing so that it is automatically added.

Comment: Untested, but you may want to have a look at this [IFTT applet](https://ifttt.com/applets/124489p-email-create-google-calendar-quick-add-event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is some plain text way of writing something and emailing so that it is automatically added.

There is no plain text method for adding calendar entries to a recipient's calendar (can you imagine the abuse?).

As I understand it, Google will "*automatically scan*" certain incoming emails, picking out important pieces of information. This feature is documented here: Events from [Gmail](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084018?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

In the Troubleshooting section, there is a section titled "*Events from Gmail don't show up in Calendar*", which explains why things might not appear.

[image: screenshot of linked google support page]

---

An alternate option might be to send an [iCalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) invitation (`*.ics` file) as an attachment, with a suitable message in the email's body.

Gmail will show a calendar banner over the email, allowing you to easily click "*Yes*" / "*Maybe*" / "*No*" in response, and the event will be added to your calendar tentatively:

[image: example tentative appointment] → [image: accepted appointment]

Comment: Thanks - I figured as much. I was kinda hoping to be able to white list an email address. The best I could find was email markup.